# using two cases of exists in sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a query that says `If the customer has no invoice, but has an appointment in the last 6 months, please give me their clientId and name`  The following result returns and empty set.

```
SELECT clients.clientId, clients.studentFirstName, clients.studentLastName 
FROM  clients, invoices, appointments 
WHERE (NOT EXISTS 
          (SELECT * 
           FROM invoices, clients 
           WHERE invoices.clientId = clients.clientId)) 
AND (EXISTS 
         (SELECT * FROM appointments, clients 
         WHERE appointments.clientId = invoices.clientId 
         AND appointments.date >= DATE_ADD(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)));
```

EDIT: The query that ended up working was created after a little tweaking of john's answer:

```
 SELECT  a.clientID,
    a.studentFirstName,
    a.studentLastName
FROM    clients a 
        LEFT JOIN invoices b
            on a.clientID = b.clientID
        LEFT JOIN appointments c
            on a.clientID = c.clientID
WHERE   b.clientId IS NULL AND
    c.`date` >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT  a.ClientID,
        a.studentFirstName,
        a.clients.studentLastName
FROM    clients a 
            LEFT JOIN invoices b
                on a.ClientID = b.ClientID
            LEFT JOIN appointments c
                on a.ClientID = c.ClientID
WHERE   b.Client IS NULL AND
        c.`Date` >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

Comment: This script ended up working with some tweaking...SELECT  a.clientID,
        a.studentFirstName,
        a.studentLastName
FROM    clients a 
            LEFT JOIN invoices b
                on a.clientID = b.clientID
            LEFT JOIN appointments c
                on a.clientID = c.clientID
WHERE   b.clientId IS NULL AND
        c.`Date` >= DATE_SUB(curdate(), INTERVAL 6 MONTH)...I will also include this in it's correct form above in the original post.

Comment: thanks so much for your help!  I'll mark this correct in 3 minutes.

Comment: @radleybobins, you might want to use SELECT DISTINCT in case a client has had more than one appointment in the last 6 months, in which case you will end up with duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's supposed to be DATE_ADD and not DATE_SUB ?

You can use joins:

```
SELECT    a.clientId,
          a.studentFirstName,
          a.studentLastName
FROM      clients a
JOIN      appointments b ON a.clientId = b.clientId 
          AND b.date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH
LEFT JOIN invoices c ON a.clientId = c.clientId
WHERE     c.clientId IS NULL
```

Comment: Wow, that is a significantly better way to do it than mine...I didn't even think about using a join, even though it probably should have been my go to method.  This query also returned an empty set, but between the two of us, I'm wondering if there are no such entries on the database.  I'm going to go search for one manually and I'll report back.

Comment: I've used DATE_ADD several times for other queries, so that's likely not the problem

Comment: @radleybobins, do you want to retrieve the clients that ***have had*** an appointment in the ***last*** 6 months or have appointments within the ***next*** six months?

Comment: @radleybobins `DATE_ADD` and `DATE_SUB` are two different things. you have mentioned `but has an appointment in the last 6 months`

Comment: @john thanks for clearing that up, i was thinking about that incorrectly.  The script below worked with some extra changes